# how to set font weight in Java for Swing components

Tags: java, swing, fonts, font-size

I want to set different **font weights** for components on my JFrame dialog. How do I do this?

In the below Java statement

```
setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.BOLD, 12));
```

when I use Font.BOLD it is too bold and when I use Font.Plain it is too plain. I want something in-between.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

welle is partially correct.  You can use [TextAttributes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/font/TextAttribute.html) to obtain a font:

```
Map<TextAttribute, Object> attributes = new HashMap<>();

attributes.put(TextAttribute.FAMILY, Font.DIALOG);
attributes.put(TextAttribute.WEIGHT, TextAttribute.WEIGHT_SEMIBOLD);
attributes.put(TextAttribute.SIZE, 12);

label.setFont(Font.getFont(attributes));
```

A better approach is to derive your font from the font installed on the Swing component by the look-and-feel:

```
Font font = label.getFont();

font = font.deriveFont(
    Collections.singletonMap(
        TextAttribute.WEIGHT, TextAttribute.WEIGHT_SEMIBOLD));

label.setFont(font);
```

That will preserve the font's family and size, which users may have set in their desktop preferences for readability reasons.

Comment: I tried this with Java 8 on Windows 7 and it doesn't seem to work unfortunately, the weight specified is ignored and the regular font is always picked (I tried with the black variant of Arial, and the light variants of Myriad and Lato).

Comment: It turns out, support for weights other than regular and bold isn't implemented in java.awt.Font: https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/jdk-17+35/src/java.desktop/share/classes/java/awt/Font.java#L790

Answer (score 7):

maybe i wrong but i think class Font has only Bold ,plain  but you can change after that in number

```
setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.BOLD, 12));

setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.plain, 27));
```

but in class  `java.awt.font.TextAttribute`

you have WEIGHT_BOLD and WEIGHT_SEMIBOLD ...

Comment: that changes font-size but not font-weight. but TextAttribute sounds interesting

Comment: i know that change font-size but i think it works for your job..sorry i do my best but i think TextAttribute is work good:)

Answer (score 3):

The solution is to load by name the variant of the font, for example:

```
Font font = new Font("Segoe UI Semibold", Font.PLAIN, 12);
```