# Correctly getting the current font in Swing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, fonts

I'd like to get the current font used by my GUI to create a bold version of it. Which of the following solutions is to be preferred using pure Swing and why?

```
Font font = ...
```

1. `somethingExtendsAwtComponent.getFont();`
2. `UIManager.getLookAndFeel().getDefaults().getFont("defaultFont");`
3. `UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().getFont("defaultFont");`
4. `UIManager.getDefaults().getFont("defaultFont");`

The Javadocs are not very helpful, only saying that 4. is to be used instead of 3. because alterations on the `UIDefaults` object returned can result in incorrect behavior, something that isn't the case here.

Comment: Each type of component may have a different font, so usually you want to base the font on a particular component’s default font.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25054203/how-to-set-font-weight-in-java-for-swing-components.

Comment: only eventually **a** is returning as required *"the current font used by my GUI"*, and only for that given somethingExtendsAwtComponent - the others are returning some default font (**c** not even the default from the current L&F)

Comment: @Abra Preferably in any Swing component that is somehow labeled (JButtons, JLabels, TitledBorders, etc...). These examples are my concrete use cases.

Comment: @VGR So I have to get the default font of every relevant object and then modify it?

Comment: Essentially, yes.  You can write a single recursive method to traverse a window or other component hierarchy, updating each traversed component’s font.  Are you sure you want to do this?  There is a reason desktop environments don’t use bold fonts by default.  Bold fonts are hard to read.